# How to programmatically get Kubernetes cluster id using spring kubernetes api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

I want to fetch cluster id using java spring kubernetes api. Is there a way to get it programmatically like we get pod information using below:

```
ApiClient client  = Config.defaultClient();
CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api(client);
String continuationToken = null;
V1PodList items = api.listPodForAllNamespaces(null, continuationToken, null, null, 10, null, null, null, 10, false);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "cluster id" in this context? Do you have a link to a description?

Comment: Microservice is deployed on kubernetes. Wanted to fetch cluster id on which service is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

In **[kubernetes spring api documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-open-service-broker/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/cloud/servicebroker/model/KubernetesContext.html)** there is a detailed explanation provided for KubernetesContext class. There is a method called `getClusterid()` which will return the cluster id. Following is the explanation provided in the documentation:

> **getClusterid**
>
> public String getClusterid()
>
> Retrieve the kubernetes clusterid from the collection of platform.
>
> properties
>
> **Returns:**
> the clusterid

Note: The above information is provided by referring to the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-open-service-broker/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/cloud/servicebroker/model/KubernetesContext.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any sample or example for the same for reference?

Comment: I'm also searching for the sample code will let you know if I found any..